# trying to get sample project from Docusign to work

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I get an error when running the qs-csharp sample application provided from DocuSign.

I have configured the project in Visual Studio community edition just like the video had instructed me. When I try to send the envelope I get an error that I haven't seen anyone else get yet. The main error is Access Denied and the more detailed error is "The URL you have requested is blocked by Surf Protection. If you think this is wrong, please contact your administrator.
"

Not sure why I would get this since all the web links in the code I tried work if I try to open them from my browser. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: This is the qs-csharp sample project that runs in Visual studio. I use the IIS express feature to run the program and everything works until I try to send the envelope.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a firewall issue. The term Surf Protection is really old so it was confusing me but once I switched to a different network we have with a different firewall, it went through just fine.